# How does "ananeousthai" Ephesians 4:23 compare with "anakainosei" Romans 12:2?

Tags: word-choice

**Ephesians 4:23**

> "and to be **renewed** in the spirit of your minds". ESV. My emphasis. renewed/*ananeousthai*.  [Infinitive verb].

**Romans 12:2**

> "Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by the **renewal** of your mind, that by testing you may discern what is the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect".  renewal/*anakainosei*. [Noun].

One is a verb and one a noun. But they both have "renew" and both relate to mind/*noos*.

As these different Greek words appear in different contexts, are different
aspects of the mind described as being "renewed"?

Do these two words mean the same or are there nuanced differences in the sort of renewal being described?

Comment: Yesterday you wrote left a very encouraging constructive criticism that I took to heart.  (it disappeared from your post)  In reediting to give a more definitive answer, I basically ended up rewriting my originally answer.  Thank you for your kind constructive criticism that led me to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

The operative words here are:

**Eph 4:23 - ἀνανεόω (ananeoó)**

This verb only occurs in Eph 4:23 and is from ἀνα + νεόω = complete/up + new, an intensified form of the verb meaning to **renew**.

**Rom 12:2 - ἀνακαίνωσις (anakainósis)**

This noun only occurs in Rom 12:2 and Titus 3:5; the latter teaches that the renewing of the mind is a work of the Holy Spirit.  Again, it is from ἀνα + καίνωσις = an intensified form of the noun meaning the process of making something fresh, ie, renewal.

Allowing for the fact that one is a verb and the other a noun, the cognate meanings of both words greatly overlap and are almost synonyms.  All three verses teach that the Christian life is to be a process of renewal of the attitudes of the mind - a task done by the miraculous work of the Holy Spirit in the sinner's life.

This echoes the central teaching of the New Covenant as taught in several places:

- Heb 10:16 - This is the covenant I will make with them after those days, declares the Lord. I will put My laws in their hearts and inscribe them on their minds.
- Jer 24:7 - I will give them a heart to know Me, that I am the LORD. They will be My people, and I will be their God, for they will return to Me with all their heart.
- Jer 31:31, 33 - This is the covenant I will make with them after those days, declares the Lord. I will put My laws **in their hearts** and inscribe them **on their minds**. ... But this is the covenant I will make with the house of Israel after those days, declares the LORD. I will put My law **in their minds** and inscribe it **on their hearts**. And I will be their God, and they will be My people.
- Eze 11:19 - And I will give them singleness of heart and put **a new spirit** within them; I will remove their heart of stone and give them a heart of flesh,
- Eze 18:31 - Cast away from yourselves all the transgressions you have committed, and fashion for yourselves **a new heart and a new spirit**. Why should you die, O house of Israel?
- Eze 36:26 - I will give you **a new heart and put a new spirit** within you; I will remove your heart of stone and give you a heart of flesh.

Answer (score 1):

OP's question;

> As these different Greek words appear in different contexts, are different aspects of the mind described as being "renewed"?

This is a re-edited version from my previous post.

> The exhortation in Romans 12:2  is not to be configured to this eon, but to be transformed by the renewing of your mind.

Transformation takes place by renewing your mind. Expanding on what renewal means in this context.  First looking at the word transformed  that is used in conjunction with the word Renewed.  (ἀνακαινώσει)

> Transformed;
> 3339 metamorphóō (from 3326 /metá, "change after being with" and 3445 /morphóō, "changing form in keeping with inner reality")

> 3326 metá implying "change afterward" (i.e. what results after the activity). 3326 (metá) looks towards the after-effect (change, result) which is only defined by the context

> 3445 morphóō (from 3444 /morphḗ, "form embodying inner essence") – properly, taking on the form that properly embodies a particular inner-essence.

This  transformation happens by renewing your mind.  ἀνακαινώσει

> 342 anakaínōsis (from 303 /aná, "up, completing a process," which intensifies kainō, "make fresh, new"; see 2537 /kainós) – properly, a new development; a renewal, achieved by God's power.
> "not found exactly like this before."

> The act or process of making new again.

This is a brand new way of transforming people, not through the law, but through this new way;  through the mind being renewed in truth of what God has done.  It is revealed in the previous chapters of Romans.  Here are some highlights of what God has accomplished in Christ Jesus. that relates to a believer in Him.  Giving a believer a new mindset.  Think on these things. That is how the mind is renewed. This is truth concerning a believer.

The righteousness of God, through Jesus Christ's faith, for all and on all who are believing.

- [ ] So if one is believing this righteousness of God is now on him.
- [ ] Being justified by His grace
- [ ] Peace with God
- [ ] Reconciled to God
- [ ] Saved in His life
- [ ] Reign in life, through Jesus Christ
- [ ] Made righteous
- [ ] Walk In newness of life
- [ ] United with Christ in likenesses of His resurrection
- [ ] Know old humanity was Crucified with him
- [ ] Sin's may become body inert.
- [ ] No longer a slave to sin
- [ ] Have been justified from sin
- [ ] Live together with Christ
- [ ] Died to sin through Christ's death
- [ ] Living to God in Christ Jesus our Lord
- [ ] Presenting yourself to God as alive  from among the dead
- [ ] Members are now implements of righteousness for God
- [ ] Not under law, but under grace
- [ ] Freed from sin
- [ ] Enslaved to righteousness
- [ ] Enslaved to God, fruit for holiness
- [ ] Eonian life in Christ
- [ ] No Condemnation to those in Christ Jesus
- [ ] Set free from the law of sin and death
- [ ] No longer in the flesh
- [ ] God spirit is making its home in you
- [ ] Being led by God's Spirit
- [ ] Being a son of God
- [ ] Received the spirit of sonship
- [ ] The same spirit joins its witness with our spirit that we are children of God
- [ ] Enjoyers of  God's  allotment
- [ ] Joint enjoyers of Christ's allotment if we are Suffering with him, that we should be glorified together
- [ ] Have the first fruit of the spirit
- [ ] Creation is waiting for the unveiling of these  sons of God
- [ ] deliverance of our bodies
- [ ] The spirit is pleading for us
- [ ] Called according to His purpose
- [ ] Designates beforehand to be conformed to the image of His Son
- [ ] For him to be the first born among many brother in
- [ ] He calls, he justifies glorifies
- [ ] God is for us
- [ ] Who then is against us?
- [ ] Nothing shall separate us from the love of God in Christ Jesus
- [ ] We are more than conquerors through Him who loves us

Years later Paul wrote the book of Ephesians where things that have been hidden in God are now revealed.

This is where we find
another word in that is often translated renew as well.  (ἀνακαινώσει)

Does it mean the same thing or is it slightly different?  That is the question the OP asked.

There definitely is a slightly different meaning .

Here is another translation that gives a different   meaning to the word (ἀνακαινώσει)

> Put off, as regards your previous behavior, the old humanity which is being corrupted in accord with its seductive desires, yet to be rejuvenated in the spirit of your mind,

> and to put on the new humanity, which, in accord with God, is being created in  righteousness and benignity of the truth.  Concordant Literal

> rejuvenated
> : to make young or youthful again : give new vigor to

> : to restore to an original or new state

This word gives more clarity  since the context is in regard to a new humanity, which is being created in righteousness.  This is the new state of the new man, the second Adam.  This is where the true image of God will be seen again not only in Christ Jesus, But to all men who are being conformed into his image as well.

rejuvenated in the spirit of your mind

We have been given the mind of Christ that is controlled by His spirit.

This word takes it to the next level from where the renewing of the mind started in Romans.

This mindset contains a few of the following truths that this Regenerated mind has in the spirit of the mind.

- [ ] Every spiritual blessing among the celestials in Christ
- [ ] One is holy and flawless in His sight
- [ ] designated beforehand for the place of a sononto Him through Christ Jesus
- [ ] Deliverance through his blood
- [ ] Forgiveness of offenses
- [ ] He makes known the secret of His will
- [ ] To have an administration, The complement of the eras which is in this calling
- [ ] In which the universe is to be headed up in the Christ, in the heavens as well as on the earth
- [ ] Even in Him whom are lot is cast
  And there's so much more included in this new mindset of this regenerated humanity that  is revealed through the whole book of Ephesians.

> 365 ananeóō (from 303 /aná, "up, completing a process," which intensifies 3501 /néos, "recent, new") – properly, going up to a higher stage (level of sanctification) by God's power; divinely renewed.
> 365/ananeoō ("make new in relation to time") is only used in Eph 4:23. Here believers are reminded of God's continuous offer to bring new strides in their sanctification through "sanctified reasoning" – raising the meaning up to new levels of spiritual comprehension

> : to restore to an original or new state

It has to do with a brand new humanity, a new creation that is young.  It is still in the process of being created in Christ.

This new creation has come out of the old creation that died with Christ and was buried and has sprung up with in the second Adam, the new creation where sin no longer indwells any part of it.  The spirit of the mind has been rejuvenated and is  brand new.

> We have been given the mind of Christ.  1 corinthians 2:16

> Rejuvenate:
> To restore to youthful vigor or appearance; make young again.
> To restore to an original or new condition.

Rejuvenate is like a seed that has fallen to the ground and died.  Some time later it becomes alive again, pushing up through the dirt, leaving the old life and shell behind, emerges as a tender, new life, out of the old.

Another scripture is Colossians 3:10 that can help give more clarity to this word  ananeóō

> having put on the new,
> which is renewed in regard to knowledge, after the image of Him who did create him.  Colossians 3:10

It's like looking in a mirror now and instead of seeing an old corrupted humanity you see a beautiful new rejuvenated humanity in Christ's image.

To reinstate OP's  questions;

How does "ananeousthai" Ephesians 4:23 compare with "anakainosei" Romans 12:2?

These two words have a fine distinction of the sort of renewal being described?

Here is the quote from the Bible hub.

> Bible Commentary 23. be renewed—The Greek (ananeousthai) implies "the continued renewal in the youth of the new man." A different Greek word (anakainousthai) implies "renewal from the old state." in the spirit of your mind—As there is no Greek for "in," which there is at Eph 4:17, "in the vanity of their mind," it is better to translate, "By the Spirit of your mind," that is, by your new spiritual nature; the restored and divinely informed leading principle of the mind. The "spirit" of man in New Testament is only then used in its proper sense, as worthy of its place and governing functions, when it is one spirit with the Lord.

Comment: Your answer goes into details that mine leaves out, so+1.

Answer (score 0):

Eph 4:23 the word "*ananeousthai*" has "*neos*/new" in it.

Romans 12:2 "*anakainosei*" has "*kainos*" in it.

**From Mark 2:22**

> "..But new wine is for fresh wineskins". ESV.  [*neon*/new; *kainos*/fresh].

In Mark 2:22 we see *neos* and *kainos* used together as new fermenting expanding wine needs previously unused wineskins to absorb that expansion.

If the wineskin was made some time before that might not matter, the key point is that as it is previously unused it has the capacity to expand. *kainos* here is the quality of not having been previously used.

When a person turns from the world to follow Christ they are not to be "conformed to this world". Ro 12:2. The wineskin has to conform/expand to the
"new/*neos*" type of thinking that it "may discern what is the will of God". [Ro 12:2].

**From Colossians 3:10**

> "and have **put on** the new self, which is being renewed in knowledge after the image of its creator". [*neon*/new; *anakainoumenon*/renewed].

Again we see "*neon*" and "*kainos/anakainoumenon*" used together but with a difference between them.

**"put on"**. The new/*neon* self has "put on" as clean clothes are put on, and are kept clean from being tarnished by the world, by being different from the world; different by renewing the knowledge of Christ. Here people who have recently heard Epaphras [Col 1:7] are to maintain their different/*kainos* thinking by continuing to know Christ.

The *"neos"* wine is new, but it cannot expand if the Christian does not expand their thinking to accomodate it. Our *"neos"* clothes will not continue to look new if we do not wash them regularly. Even *kainos*/new thinking has to be *neos*/renewed.

People who have become Christians by taking on new/*kainos* thinking, including new/*neos* Christians, will need to freshen/renew/*neos*[Eph 4:23]
that new/*kainos* way of thinking.

Romans 12:2 *kainos*: knowing Jesus; a quality; a different way of thinking from the world.

Ephesians 4:23 *neos*: being free of guilt and stain; keeping the new way of thinking fresh.